# Does Couchbase/CouchDB allow me to move / skip the CRUD middle man from the server?

Tags: database-design, performance, nosql, couchbase

So currently this is a common setup:

> Client -> Ajax -> Server CRUD -> Database

Does Couchbase allow me to do this?

> Client -> Ajax -> Database

This might be more technically correct:

> Client -> Ajax REST -> Database

Does this mean that I could just have the client directly interacting with the database, therefore reducing the load on the server? Theoretically this would make scaling a website more cost efficient.

If so, has this method been increasing in popularity usage? If not, why? It seems like this is a huge advantage.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the [REST API endpoint list](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/rest-api/rest-endpoints-all.html) on the Couchbase docs site.

I think it might be hypothetically possible. You could use the [N1QL REST API](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-rest-api/index.html) to do inserts, selects, updates, and deletes.

I can't say for sure whether this is going to help scaling and load or not, but I do think you're going to have to address a number of other challenges: validation, authentication, authorization, business logic, and more.